# Why is operator<< overload not found?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, operator-overloading

I've declared an `operator<<` overload for `time_point` in the global namespace and also one for `a::Foo` in the `a` namespace. When I try to print a `time_point` in a function also defined in namespace `a`, I get the error:

> Invalid operands to binary expression.

Why is this, and what is the best solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os,
                         const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point &time_point);
namespace a {
class Foo;
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const a::Foo &foo);
void print_time() {
  std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now(); // error here!
}
}

int main() {
  a::print_time();
}
```

Comment: It's because of [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Putting the overload in `namespace std { /* operator overload */ }` makes it work, but I honestly don't know if this is entirely correct or a good solution.

Comment: It might be better to define a new function rather than overloading the `<<` operator for standard types, some future standard could declare its own operator which could be ambiguous with yours

Comment: @churill that's not allowed (see [17.6.4.2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/library#namespace.std-1)). Also there's no guarantee that a standard library doesn't provide such an overload already. In which case the overload would become ambiguous. The whole idea is bad to begin with.

Comment: If you want to acceptably add a function to std, you have to make your own class (which can be derived from a standard class)

Answer (score 1):

The *reason* is simple: `a::operator<<` **shadows** your `::operator<<` since they have the same name.  This is why operators basically have to share a namespace with their classes: such shadowing is to be expected, and so **ADL** (as discussed in the comments) is the only reliable means of finding them.